# Save php variable as null for sql

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have made a program to read 3 inputs on another page, the ID, code1, and code2.

One is a code to have easy to search, while the other 2 are variables that will be used to sum, subtract, multiply an divide and then save it all in a database

I have connected it to this php code:

```
if (isset($_POST["ID"]))
 {
    $id=($_POST["ID"]);
   $val1=($_POST["code1"]);
   $val2=($_POST["code2"]);

if ($val2 == 0){
    $sum = $val1 + $val2;
    $res = $val1 - $val2;
    $mul = $val1 * $val2;
    $div = NULL;
}else{
    $sum = $val1 + $val2;
    $res = $val1 - $val2;
    $mul = $val1 * $val2;
    $div = $val1 / $val2;
}

 $cnn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","CC2CRO","ejercicios");
 if ($cnn) {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('CONEXION EXITOSA  
 !!!!')</SCRIPT>");         
    $sqlnr = mysqli_query($cnn, "INSERT INTO calculadora (Id, Valor1, 
 Valor2, Suma, Resta, Multiplicacion, Division) VALUES ('$id', '$val1', 
 '$val2', '$sum', '$res', '$mul', '$div')");
```

That is connected to MySQL database, so far it has worked, like for example I put OP45, 12, 3
when I see my database is saved as `OP45` `12` `3` `15` `9` `36` `4`
my issue is with when I use 0 for $val2, I wanted to save it as null since you can´t divide by 0, but when I run it it leaves the whole row empty, only does that when $val2 is 0, if $val2 is 1 or more it fills the entire row.

On my database Id is varchar and the rest are decimal (6,2), Id is PK and Not Null, also Valor1 and Valor2 are Not Null too.

below the code block from above I have this other one

```
 if ($sqlnr)
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('REGISTRO ALMACENADO CORRECTAMENTE !!!!')</SCRIPT>");
    else{
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('EL REGISTRO NO PUDO SER GUARDADO !!!!')</SCRIPT>");
    }
```

The first one is seen if it was saved in the database and the second one if it wasn't saved, so when val2 is 0 it always gives me the 2nd message.

Comment: Have you considered an insert trigger in MySQL to check if zero and update to null?

Comment: before divide you should check `if` the `$val2` is `0` then `$div=0` like `if($val2==0){$div=0;}`

Comment: _“I wanted to save it as null since you can´t divide by 0”_ - how would that help? `5 / NULL` still gets you a “Division by zero” warning in PHP.

Comment: I have tried to put $div=0; when I do that it does put it as 0 on the database but I want it to remain as NULL when $val2 is 0, I have tried other things such as $div=null; $div=NULL; $div="(NULL)"; $div="NULL"; others like that but it doesn't save

Comment: how is that column/table defined? Is a NULL value allowed for `Division`? Did you check for mysqli_error?

Comment: I have this one set up so if it is 0 it doesn't do the division
`if ($val2 == 0){
    $sum = $val1 + $val2;
    $res = $val1 - $val2;
    $mul = $val1 * $val2;
    $div = NULL;`
And have the else set up afterwards if $val2 is more than 0

Comment: yes I have left NULL as a value allowed for Division

Comment: as far as I remember, NULL shouldn't have quotes around it, but `$div` should be the literal string 'NULL' in your case.

Comment: You could/should switch to prepared stements, that would make all of that easier...

Comment: and again: _"did you check for mysqli_error"_?

Comment: The fact that you get the error message after the query indicates that you get an error from the db and mysqli_query returns FALSE. Please do call mysqli_error on false and post the result.

Comment: It doesn't show mysqli_error or at least I don't have it set up to call it the only errors I have if there is one on the code I see it on the page below the inputs and it shows me in what line I have the error but not for mysqli

Comment: In your query, try changing `'$div'` to `" . ($val2 == 0 ? "NULL" : "'$div'") . "`

Comment: @Nick Thanks seems like that worked changing the $div in the if statement to  $div = "", and adding that line into the query, I don't know that much so I been reading some documents to work on my code, mind if you explain that line to me or giving me a link to where I can read about that line since from what I have read I haven't found something like that to help me.

Comment: @AnguisNox if you print out the query, you'll see that when `$val2 == 0` the query shows the value being inserted into `Division` as `NULL` rather than a blank string. This is probably allowing the column to take a default value, or even be NULL if that is allowed, where a blank string is probably not a valid value for the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
$div = NULL;  to  $div = 'NULL';
```

then remove single quotes in '$div' in sql string `( '$div' to $div )`

```
$sqlnr = mysqli_query($cnn, "INSERT INTO calculadora (Id, Valor1, 
        Valor2, Suma, Resta, Multiplicacion, Division) VALUES ('$id', '$val1', 
       '$val2', '$sum', '$res', '$mul', $div)");
```